# Handling Self Intersecting SQL Geometries with OGR

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, gda2020

Is there a way to validate/fix self intersecting SQL geometries when pushing a SQL table into a new SQL database using OGR? This is MSSQL. I want to avoid having to manually fix potentially many badly digitised lines or polygons. Is there any difference in validating features using Pythons OGR libraries or via an ogr script? Below is the original script with database/table names replaced. This pushes the table out to a new database and shifts it to the new GDA2020 datum. The issue is that if a table has dodgy geometries it comes across empty. The particular table I am looking at has many thousands of geometries.

```
ogr2ogr -s_srs "+proj=utm +zone=55 +south +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +wktext +nadgrids=C:\Program Files\blahblahblah\GDA94_GDA2020_conformal.gsb" -t_srs "+proj=utm +zone=55 +south +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +wktext" -f "MSSQLSPATIAL" "MSSQL:driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=blahblahblah;Database=blahblahblah;Trusted_Connection=Yes" "MSSQL:driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=blahblahblah;Tables=dbo.blahblahblah;Database=blahblahblah;Trusted_Connection=Yes" -nln OutputTableName
```

Comment: Have you tried https://gdal.org/user/sql_sqlite_dialect.html#sql-sqlite-dialect with something like `-dialect SQLite -sql "select ST_MakeValid(geometry) as geometry, attribute_1, attribute_2... FROM my_table"`?